# mke2fs - answer to an "overwrite" question from a script

Tags: shell-script, filesystems, pipe, alpine-linux

I use `mke2fs` utility to create a file system. If file system already exists, I get a confirmation prompt:

```
~# mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdf 
mke2fs 1.46.2 (28-Feb-2021)
/dev/xvdf contains a ext4 file system labelled 'Data'
        created on Sun Oct 10 22:06:41 2021
Proceed anyway? (y,N) n
```

So far so good. Now I want to put this command into a script, and make it silently select `no` in such occasions:

```
~# echo 'n' | mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdf 
mke2fs 1.46.2 (28-Feb-2021)
Creating filesystem with 262144 4k blocks and 65536 inodes
Filesystem UUID: c3136577-5ef3-435c-a02c-ebae8d1f4e32
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (8192 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done
```

??? There is no interactive prompt in this case, it just proceeds with the job. Also tried with `expect`, and `yes n` as suggested by @kjensenxz later - there is no prompt either. It doesn't get stuck waiting for the input - there is no question at all, as if `mke2fs` magically detects that it was run with a piped input and then it doesn't even try to read it.

`-q` flag has no effect on this.

The script runs on alpine linux, if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to `mkfs.ext4` that tells it to abort if it's found a filesystem. Instead, you need to perform that check yourself. (I would imagine that `mkfs.ext4` only bothers to ask for confirmation if *stdin* is connected to a terminal, and if not it assumes it wouldn't get an answer so continues anyway. This would be a reasonable approach that's similar to `ls` and `ls | cat` outputting different layouts.)

Here are examples of device filesystem enquiries on a Pi,

```
file -s /dev/mmcblk0p1
/dev/mmcblk0p1: DOS/MBR boot sector, code offset 0x3c+2, OEM-ID "mkfs.fat", sectors/cluster 16, root entries 512, Media descriptor 0xf8, sectors/FAT 32, sectors/track 63, heads 255, sectors 129024 (volumes > 32 MB), reserved 0x1, serial number 0x22e0c711, label: "boot       ", FAT (16 bit)

file -s /dev/mmcblk0p2
/dev/mmcblk0p2: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=202638e1-4ce4-45df-9a00-ad725c2537bb (needs journal recovery) (extents) (large files)

file -s /dev/mmcblk0p3
/dev/mmcblk0p3: LVM2 PV (Linux Logical Volume Manager), UUID: 40t385-3Q2C-u3Qz-TN5b-1fI1-0oYC-PsMQ3c, size: 27618967552
```

There are quite a number of possible options - considerably more than I've shown here - so it's probably easier to look for the "empty" case and only continue if the intended device matches this. For experimentation you could use `dd if=/dev/zero` or `dd if=/dev/urandom`, but both have `file -s` return `data` as the file type:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=100 of=/tmp/100M.dat
100+0 records in
100+0 records out
104857600 bytes (105 MB, 100 MiB) copied, 0.487274 s, 215 MB/s

lodev=$(losetup --find --show /tmp/100M.dat ); echo $lodev
/dev/loop0

file -s $lodev
/dev/loop0: data

losetup -d $lodev
rm /tmp/100M.dat
```

The code could be something like this,

```
#!/bin/sh
device=/dev/xvdf

magic=$(file -s "$device" 2>&1)
if [ "$magic" = "$device: data" ]
then
    # It isn't an obvious filesystem
    mkfs.ext4 ... "$device"
else
    # Uh oh
    printf "%s\n" "Cowardly refusing to create a filesystem on ${magic%%,*}" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Thank you, looks I'll end up doing checks as you describe. It's a shame mke2fs makes those checks, but doesn't provide a command line option to control them. I still try to find out what is the difference between the calls with and w/o a pipe, and if there is a way to 'switch' between them.

Answer (score 0):

`yes n | mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdXY`

See [`yes(1)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/yes.1.html).

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but that didn't work either. I updated the question to make it clear what happens.